# Needing Composer to Add Mailgun in cPanel?

Tags: php, email, composer-php, cpanel, mailgun

I'm obviously inexperienced when it comes to coding because I'm self taught but I was wondering if it's completely necessary to download Composer just to use the Mailgun files I've uploaded into cPanel in Godaddy. Chances are I need Composer or if I don't, I'm probably just messing up my own code. Either way, I want to figure out how to add Mailgun to my web app.

I've uploaded the file from Github into my cPanel directory under the folder "email". Here's the code for my php file:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/email/mailgun-php-master/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
$mailgun = new Mailgun('*I added my key here*', new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client());
?>
```

How do I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: See if the file that you are including exists with file_exists().  If it's the correct path, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Do you mean the 'email/mailgun-php-master/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php'? I just checked and it says true

Comment: So, what is failing?  Anything?  If nothing is failing, then it's probably working.  Composer just helps deal with dependencies, you don't need it, but it helps to learn how to use it, since a large portion of people do.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. It only fails when I include the line '$mailgun = new Mailgun('*I added my key here*', new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client());' after I put in my API key

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client' not found in /home/nslattery1021/public_html/test2.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/nslattery1021/public_html/test2.php on line 6" I've added displayed errors and this came up.

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, check out the documentation.  The Guzzle6\Client() doesn't seem to match up with what you say you're trying to do and you're not necessarily including that code. https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php